# Uri Parameter in RESTful Post Method

Tags: java, rest, post, uri, html-select

I am developing a java RESTful web application. In one web page in particular I have, among the other components, a drop-down list:

```
  <select name="source" id="source">
    <option uri="http://localhost:9091/project/test/source/database" name="database"   count="1">database</option>
    <option uri="http://localhost:9091/project/test1/source/report2" name="report2"   count="1">report2</option>
  </select>
```

I would like to obtain, after the post request, the uri of the option selected by the user.
To get all the parameters to the POST method I wrote this:

> ```
> @POST
> @Consumes(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
> public Response mapDBSource(@FormParam("project") URI projectId,
>           @FormParam("source") URI sourceId, 
>           @FormParam("dest_title") String destTitle,
>           @FormParam("dest_graph_uri") URI targetGraph) throws WebApplicationException {
>     Response response = null;
> ```

but the content of the URI Object SourceId is not the value of the uri, but just the name of the source. What is wrong with my code? How could I get the uri without showing it? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you use

```
 <option value="..."
```

instead of

```
 <option uri="..."
```